# Testing and creating objects with ForeignKey fields

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to write some unit tests and I'm creating a few dummy objects for this purpose. I have a model `speaker` which partially looks like this :

```
class speaker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    ...
```

and a class `talk` which looks partially like this:

```
class talk(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 255) 
    ...
    speakers = models.ManyToManyField('speaker') 
    ...
```

My test set up looks like this:

```
class TalkTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):

        speaker.objects.create(
            name = "John Smith",
            email = "john@john.com"
            )

        talk.objects.create(
            title = "Writing unit tests",
            summary = "How to write unit tests",
            speakers = "john@john.com"
            )

    def test_talk_URLs(self):
        testSpeak = speaker.objects.get(name="John Smith")
        testTalk = talk.objects.get(title="Writing unit tests")

        self.assertEqual(testSpeak.email, "john@john.com")
```

However I get the following traceback error

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_talk_URLs (core.tests.TalkTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/rony/Documents/rehab-lightning-talks/core/tests.py", line 43, in setUp
speakers = "1"
File "/home/rony/Documents/rehab-lightning-talks/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 149, in create
return self.get_query_set().create(**kwargs)
File "/home/rony/Documents/rehab-lightning-talks/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 414, in create
obj = self.model(**kwargs)
File "/home/rony/Documents/rehab-lightning-talks/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 415, in __init__
raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])
TypeError: 'speakers' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Am I not referencing the foreign key correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question about ManyToMany fields, not ForeignKeys.

For an M2M, you can't do it as part of `create` - you need to set it afterwards (because an m2m relationship is really a record in a third, linking, table, so you need the PK of the original model which you only get after it is created).

```
    john = speaker.objects.create(
        name = "John Smith",
        email = "john@john.com"
    )

    unit = talk.objects.create(
        title = "Writing unit tests",
        summary = "How to write unit tests",
    )

    unit.speakers.add(john)
```

I should also note that this is not a good unit test. The mechanics of model instance creation and saving is well tested by Django's own tests. Your unit tests should test your actual logic.